BSP Tree Troubles and Unpredictable Results
I've been trying to fix this problem myself for ages, but I really do need help. I'm creating a BSP tree for my 3D game (baked in the map files, quake style) to replace my existing naïve collision & raycast solutions. However, I seem to be doing nothing correctly.
THE ISSUE:
For some unknown reason (to me), it seems my algorithm for splitting faces is just.. wrong.. in a way that I find hard to describe. It seems that some BSP nodes that should be empty are marked solid, and some faces seem to cut into BSP nodes that they have no reason to cut into. I'll supply a video below the code to better show what I mean.

Now, I'll supply the code and video of my troubles, and then I'll explain in more depth what I believe the issue is, and my struggles with fixing it.
This class manages stuff with the root node and keeping track of nodes:
(the list of temporary nodes and splitting functions are only used in the compiler, but including the #ifs kinda breaks the code display)
public static class BSPRoot
{
    public static BSPNode[] nodes;
    public static List<BSPNode> tempNodes = new List<BSPNode>();

    public static void Cut(Plane splittingPlane, Brush[] brushes, BoundingBox[] brushBounds, int brushFrom, int faceFrom)
    {
        Stack<BSPNode> stack = new Stack<BSPNode>();
        stack.Push(tempNodes[0]);

        while(stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var node = stack.Pop();

            if(node.split)
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(node.splittingPlane.Normal * node.splittingPlane.D, splittingPlane.D * splittingPlane.Normal) <= float.Epsilon) continue;

                stack.Push(tempNodes[node.front]);
                stack.Push(tempNodes[node.back]);
            }
            else
            {
                node.Cut(splittingPlane,brushes,brushBounds,brushFrom,faceFrom);
            }
        }
    }
    public static BSPHit TraceRay(Ray ray, float distance)
    {
        BSPHit hit = new BSPHit { point = ray.Position + ray.Direction * distance, normal = ray.Direction };

        if (recursiveTrace(0, ray.Position, ray.Position + ray.Direction * distance, out Vector3 intersect))
        {
            hit = new BSPHit { point = intersect, hit = true };
        }

        return hit;
    }

    private static bool recursiveTrace(int node_num, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, out Vector3 intersection)
    {
        if (!nodes[node_num].split && nodes[node_num].solid)
        {
            intersection = p1;
            return true;
        }
        else if (!nodes[node_num].split)
        {
            intersection = p2;
            return false;
        }

        BSPNode node = nodes[node_num];
        Plane plane = node.splittingPlane;

        float t1 = plane.DotCoordinate(p1);
        float t2 = plane.DotCoordinate(p2);

        if (t1 > float.Epsilon && t2 > float.Epsilon)
            return recursiveTrace(node.front, p1, p2, out intersection);
        if (t1 <= float.Epsilon && t2 <= float.Epsilon)
            return recursiveTrace(node.back, p1, p2, out intersection);

        float frac = t1 / (t1 - t2);

        Vector3 mid = p1 + frac * (p2 - p1);

        if (recursiveTrace((t1 > float.Epsilon ? node.front : node.back), p1, mid, out intersection))
            return true;

        return recursiveTrace((t1 > float.Epsilon ? node.back : node.front), mid, p2, out intersection);
    }
}

This class is the actual BSP node class
[System.Serializable]
public class BSPNode
{
    public const int ClipNode = 2;
    public const int SkyboxNode = 4;

    //public Vector3 splitPos, splitNormal; // Plane that splits the room
    public Plane splittingPlane;
    public int front;
    public int back;
    public int nodeFlag;
    public int[] nodeContents = [];
    public bool solid,split;
    public int depth;
    
    List<BSPNode> Nodes => BSPRoot.tempNodes;
    public void Cut(Plane splittingPlane, Brush[] brushes, BoundingBox[] brushBounds, int brushFrom, int faceFrom)
    {
        if (!nodeContents.Contains(brushFrom)) return;

        this.splittingPlane = splittingPlane;

        var backContents = new List<int>() { brushFrom };
        var frontContents = new List<int>();

        foreach (int content in nodeContents)
        {
            if (content == brushFrom) continue;

            bool backside = false, frontside = false;
            var boundsSide = splittingPlane.Intersects(brushBounds[content]);

            if (boundsSide == PlaneIntersectionType.Intersecting)
            {
                foreach (var vertex in brushes[content].vertices)
                {
                    float dotCoord = splittingPlane.DotCoordinate(vertex + brushes[content].position);
                    if (dotCoord <= float.Epsilon)
                        backside = true;
                    else
                        frontside = true;

                    //No need to keep checking.
                    if (backside && frontside) break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                backside = boundsSide == PlaneIntersectionType.Back;
                frontside = !backside;
            }

            if (backside) backContents.Add(content);
            if (frontside) frontContents.Add(content);
        }

        front = Nodes.Count;
        back = Nodes.Count + 1;
        Nodes.Add(new BSPNode { nodeContents = frontContents.ToArray(), depth = depth + 1 });
        Nodes.Add(new BSPNode { nodeContents = backContents.ToArray(), depth = depth + 1, solid = true });

        split = true;
    }
}

Perhaps those with the quantum-thinking cranium that I lack can already spot issues, but lastly I'll provide how these functions are used
            BSPRoot.tempNodes = new List<BSPNode>() { new BSPNode() };
            BSPRoot.tempNodes[0].nodeContents = brushIDs;
            Object splitObject = new object();
            Parallel.For(0, BSPRoot.tempNodes[0].nodeContents.Length, i =>
            {
                var brush = brushes[BSPRoot.tempNodes[0].nodeContents[i]];
                for (int f = 0; f < brush.faces.Length; f++)
                {
                    var face = brush.faces[f];
                    var plane = new Plane(brush.vertices[face.indices[0]]+brush.position,face.normal);
                    
                    lock(splitObject)
                    {
                        BSPRoot.Cut(plane, brushes, brushBounds, i, f);
                    }
                }
            });

And, because I dont find it necessary to post the entirety of my brush struct, I'll just explain that each brush stores vertices and faces, and those faces store their normals and indices into the brush vertices.
Now, the video
To explain what you'll see, I'm noclipping around with a game entity in front of the camera, I'm testing a ray (via the BSP ray traversal function) and placing the object wherever that ray hits (with a maximum distance from the camera set to ~2 units). You can see the inconsistencies very clearly.
Here's the video

I would really appreciate the help, this has been the biggest pain in the arse for me for several months, and I cant even begin to understand what's causing it.
Thank you!

EDIT: Small addendum, I'm not splitting any of the faces of the brushes, if a brush is on both sides of the tree I simply add it to both sides and leave it there. I dont know if this could potentially be causing an issue, but regardless I'd like to put that in here. Also also, I know my code isn't top tier quality, but I'd really prefer this to be more about the issue and fixing it than about my coding style. Thank you thank you!!

I believe I have fixed the issues presented
But, just in case SOMEONE out there needs this, I will share what I found.

I removed any code in my splitting functions that would ignore splitting planes (except for the bit that made sure the node contains the brush that the plane came from, that has to stay), I was trying to do some premature error handling but in practice I realized this was causing more errors than was solving. In a brush-mapping environment, just trust the splitting planes no-matter what. I also realized that you CANNOT parallelize BSP tree generation the way I have here, as every step depends on the previous step. Perhaps there's a different way to speed it up, but do not attempt to do it the way my code did, it just broke everything. I also cannot find a good way to sort my brushes by size without mangling the data, though I believe I can find a way around this.
To anyone that may stumble upon this with similar problems, I highly suggest creating a small map and adding one thing at a time until it breaks, fixing the break, and continue building until failure again. That's the only way I was able to solve these problems on my own.
